# Android: How to store value in main activity's variable?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, android-asynctask

I want to store some values on a main activity's variable after parsing an xml file from the net, I have the following codes, it runs but then it force closes:

```
private class parseXMLAsync extends AsyncTask <String, String, String>{

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(PARSE_XML);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try{
            Engagia.this.url.openConnection();
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            ExampleHandler myExampleHandler = new ExampleHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myExampleHandler);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(Engagia.this.url.openStream()));

            List<ParsedExampleDataSet> parsedExampleDataSet = myExampleHandler.getParsedData();

            Iterator i;
            i = parsedExampleDataSet.iterator();
            ParsedExampleDataSet dataItem;

            while(i.hasNext()){
                    dataItem = (ParsedExampleDataSet) i.next();
                    String folder = dataItem.getParentTag();


                    if( folder == "Videos"  ){

                        MainAct.this.videoNames[MainAct.this.videoCount] = dataItem.getName();

                        MainAct.this.videoCount++;
                    }

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String lenghtOfFile) {
        try{
            if( mProgressDialog.isShowing() ){
                dismissDialog(PARSE_XML);
            }
            //String str_contents = null;
            /*
            for(String str : MainAct.this.videoNames ){
                str_contents = str_contents + str + "\n";
            }
            */

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.toString());
        }
        PopIt("Parsing Done", "STR CONTENTS >> " + Engagia.this.videoNames[0], "Denied");
    }
}
```

The logcat says:
[image]

Comment: Debug your code to see where the NullPointerException occurs. It should happen in line 283.

Comment: Hi Kris, Can you tell in which statement do you get this error

Comment: I found an answer [on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175241/android-specify-array-size/). This is how I store the values to the array variable of my main activity. Thanks a lot for all you help. :)

Answer (score 1):

To Store value in MainAct activity

First make sure MainAct activity is not finished while you are using Async task. because you want to store the values as instance variable of MainAct

Avoid assigning values like following

```
MainAct.this.videoNames[MainAct.this.videoCount] = dataItem.getName();
```

Better create a method in MainAct  which will set value of `videoNames` there. But call that method in AsyncTask class either using static method or using instance of that method.

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: Thanks for your response @Deepak, how do I make sure MainAct activity is not finished while you are using Async task?

Comment: I created a method in the MainAct and called it in the AyncTask, it did the same.

Comment: MianAct will not be finished if you donot call finish() explicitly. Anyway you can create a method to get the instance of the class. If that method returns null that means the activity doesnot exists