# Android: Specify array size?

Tags: java, android, arrays

anyone knows how to specify array size?

```
public String[] videoNames = {""}
```

the array above can accomodate only one value. i want to extend how many values this array can accomodate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want dynamic size then use [arraylist](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html). something like:

```
public ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

...

myList.add("blah");

...

for(int i = 0, l = myList.size(); i < l; i++) {
  // do stuff with array items
  Log.d("myapp", "item: " + myList.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should write it like this.

```
String[] videoNames = new String[5]; // create videoNames array with length = 5
for(int i=0;i<videoNames.length();i++)
{
   // IMPORTANT : for each videoName, instantiate as new String.
   videoNames[i] = new String(""); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use as:

```
public String[] videoNames = new String[SIZE]; // SIZE is an integer
```

or use [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for resizable array implementation.

---

**EDIT**:
and initialize it like this:

```
int len = videoNames.length();
for(int idx = 0; idx < len; idx++) {
   videoNames[idx] = ""; 
}
```

---

With [ArrayList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

```
ArrayList<String> videoNames = new ArrayList<String>();
// and insert 
videoNames.add("my video");
```

Comment: Hi @John, thanks for your response. But how can I use an array list and how can I initialize an array properly coz when I initialize the array to null, my code returns nullPointerException... Sorry for the noob question

Comment: Is there a way to specify unlimited array size?

Comment: @Kris: then use `ArrayList` class.

Answer (score 2):

Use ArrayList if you want to add elements dynamically. Array is static in nature.

[How to add elements to array list](http://www.roseindia.net/java/beginners/array_list_demo.shtml)

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an arraylist as written in your commnet here is an arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> videoNames =new ArrayList<String>();
```

add as many as you want no need to give size

```
    videoNames.add("yourstring");
videoNames.add("yourstring");
videoNames.add("yourstring");
videoNames.add("yourstring");
```

to empty the list

```
 videoNames.clear();
```

to get a string use

```
String a=videoNames.get(2);
```

2 is your string index